# About $C^k$ function spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I present my problem with an example.

I always know that $|x| \in C^0(\mathbb{R})$

Now I see, on the italian Wikipedia, this page:

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_C_di_una_funzione

It says that $|x| \in C^0(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R\setminus\{0\}})$

Does the last statement add better information about the function ?

If the answer is yes, the things get quite complicated.

So, to describe the smoothness of a function I can take any combination of classes $C^k(A)$, with union and intersection between the classes, where k is arbitrary and A is an arbitrary set.

Comment: The statement is an attempt to say that a certain function is continuous everywhere and continuously infinitely differentiable away from zero. The notation, however, is atrocious. For one thing "$|x|$" is not a function--is is the value of a function at the point $x$; for another, the sets of functions described do not intersect. The functions in each class are defined in different domains. Yes, I understand everything that is implicit here, but it is terribly informal and sloppy notation.

Comment: Can exactly what $C^k$ denotes please (just so I know if I have it right)

Comment: $C^k$ denotes nothing by itself, I mean $C^k(A)$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Alec: $C^k$ without further context usually denotes the class of functions that are $k$-times differentiable.

Comment: k-times continuosly differentiable

Answer (score 1):

Of course it adds more information. I did not understand your last paragraph and why things get quite complicated, though.

Being smooth (or $C^\infty$) is not a property of the function *per se*, you have to ask: **Where?** 
The function $|x|$ is in $C^0(\mathbb R)$ because it's continuos everywhere. It's not differentiable everywhere, though, because in $0$ we have problems. So $|x| \notin C^1(\mathbb R)$.

On the other hand, if you exclude the single point $0$, then you find that the function is infinietly differentiable, and so $|x|$ *also* belongs to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R\setminus\{0\}})$.

Of course since $|x|$ is in both $C^\infty(\mathbb{R\setminus\{0\}})$ and $C^0(\mathbb R)$, we write $|x| \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R\setminus\{0\}}) \cap C^0(\mathbb R)$

Comment: @Valerio There are literally an infinite number of ways to classify a function. It depends on what you are interested in and what properties you care about. for example $|x| \in L^1_{loc}$, and hence also in $\mathcal D'$. It depends on the point of view you want to adopt.

Comment: Complicated in the sense to find the best classification of a function. You have said that $|x| \in C^0(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R\setminus\{0\}})$ is a better description than $|x| \in C^0(\mathbb{R})$.
But is it the best possible ?

Comment: @Valerio The point I was trying to make in my last comment is precisely this: there is no such thing as a "best possible representation". It depends on what you are interested in

Comment: Classification is usually applied to relevance: if we're interested in showing that $f(x)=|x|$ is not everywhere differentiable, we can classify it as $C^0$. Now if we think it in a bit broader sense, we could say that it is somewhere differentiable, so there exists neighborhoods where $f(x) \in C^\infty$, so could classify it as $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$